# Cross compare two array elements

Tags: php, arrays

After a lot of API calls and loops I have created an array.  This array takes the following form

```
2 => array:3 [▼
    "someInfo" => array:1 [▶]
    "existingIDs" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => "123456"
      ]
    ]
    "idList" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => "123456"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => "777564"
      ]
    ]
]
```

The part I am interested in is existingIDs and idList.  The problem is that some ids are appearing in both array elements, so in the above example the id 123456 appears in both.
What I need to do is cross compare these two elements and perhaps create a new element with unique ids.  So the above example may turn into something like this

```
2 => array:3 [▼
    "someInfo" => array:1 [▶]
    "existingIDs" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => "123456"
      ]
    ]
    "idList" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => "123456"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => "777564"
      ]
    ]
    "uniqueList" => array:2 [
      0 => array:1 [
        "id" => "123456"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [
        "id" => "777564"
      ]
    ]
]
```

How could something like this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: I assume in your example that 123456 should not be part of the new element? Just making sure. You will have to iterate through idList while keeping a running list of touched IDs. Add an ID to this list the first time you encounter it and subsequent times, skip it if it's part of your tracked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach with `array_column`(available since PHP 5.5), `array_merge` and `array_unique` functions:

```
$arr =  [
    "someInfo" => [],
    "existingIDs" => [
        ["id" => "123456"]
    ],
    "idList" => [
      ["id" => "123456"],
      ["id" => "777564"],
      ["id" => "777564"]
    ]
];

$all_ids = array_merge(array_column($arr['existingIDs'], 'id'), array_column($arr['idList'], 'id'));
$arr['uniqueList'] = array_unique($all_ids);

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [someInfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [existingIDs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123456
                )
        )

    [idList] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123456
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 777564
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 777564
                )
        )

    [uniqueList] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [2] => 777564
        )
)
```